# Search for a pattern in files with outputing the result

Tags: linux, search, command-line, grep

How to search for a pattern in files in a directory with:

1. .php files
2. output the matched line

I'm trying like this:

```
grep -lir "eval" --include '*.php' ./
```

But it's not enough.

### Second part

Also, a second part that I want to search in php code only. So it means the matched pattern should be after `<?` and not after `?>`.

Comment: `grep` can't limit its searches to specific lines. You need to use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: are you looking for files that contain the string `.php` in their names and then contain `eval` in their contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec awk '/<\?/,/\?>/ && /eval/' {} \;
```

`/<\?/,/\?>/` specifies the range of lines between `<?` and `?>`.

Comment: thanks. but some php code does not have closing `?>`. so `eval` can be after `<?` and not before `?>`

Comment: I think that's OK. When you use a range expression in awk, it's true for all lines starting with one that matches the beginning of the range, and stops being true when it matches the end. If it reaches the end of the file, it never stops being true. It doesn't search first for the last line to see if it exists.